# Why is error coming from requiring my module?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I'm trying to load a script and use it's functionality, and I have a require.js error.

```
const pro = require('./pro');

(() => {
  const loadModule = () => {
    window.pro = pro.init(window);
  };
 // some code goes here
  let $rendered;
  Object.defineProperty(window, 'rendered', {
    get: () => $rendered,
    set: (newValue) => {
      $rendered = newValue;
      loadModule();
    },
  });
})();
```

And when trying to load the code, I have a require.js error:

```
Uncaught Error: Module name "pro" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])
```

I've read the require.js solution, and when I tried it, my `eslint` rule marked it as an error, so I've figured out that I'm doing something wrong..

```
(() => {
  const loadModule = () => {
    require(['./pro'], pro => {
      window.pro = pro.init(window);
    });

  };
  // some code goes here
  let $rendered;
  Object.defineProperty(window, 'rendered', {
    get: () => $rendered,
    set: (newValue) => {
      $rendered = newValue;
      loadModule();
    },
  });
})();
```

What am I doing wrong?
Why does that happening, and what is the best practice?

Comment: The first code example is a NodeJS way of importing modules. That's why its not working for RequireJS. What kind of error does the eslint produce?

Comment: @Łukasz Hi, the error: 4:5  error  Unexpected require()  global-require

Comment: It looks like you've applied this rule https://eslint.org/docs/rules/global-require The rule expects require() on top of the file. You've got require() inside the function, it produces the error. Please see code examples from attached link.